# What's the difference between pyodbc and MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql-python, pyodbc

I have some code written with pyodbc on win x64 using python 2.6 and I get no problem.
Using the same code switching to MySQLdb I get errors.

Example. Long object not iterable....

whats the difference between pyodbc and MySQLdb?

EDIT

```
import csv, pyodbc, os 
import numpy as np

cxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MySQL;PWD=me') 
import MySQLdb
cxn =  MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",user="root",passwd ="me")

csr = cxn.cursor()


try:

   csr.execute('Call spex.updtop')

   cxn. commit

except: pass 

csr.close()
cxn.close() 
del csr, cxn
```

Comment: that is? whats  obvious to you may not be to me

Comment: The obvious is that pyodbc uses ODBC and MySQLdb uses the MySQL client libraries. If you want to know anything beyond that then you'll need to show code.

Comment: There isnt code.  The above call a SP within Mysql. Seems MySQL gets hung up on (null)'s. Thats what have run into so far on Win. On fedora, st= csr.execute("select ......from ......"), d =list(st)...throws 'long' object is not iterable.

Comment: There has to be code. How else would you be doing it in Python?

Comment: Good start with the code.  Can you post `sp.updtop`?

Comment: Another thing to try is if you get the error when using [oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/).

Comment: That I cant post, But there are columns that have (null) in them, when there is no value. Error msg is: Table34.py:13: Warning: Incorrect decimal value: ' ' for column 'RFoc' at row 14
  csr.execute('Call spex.updtop')

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing code, it's not obvious why you're getting errors.  You can connect to MySQL databases using either one, and they both implement version 2.x of the Python DB API, though their underlying workings are totally different, as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams commented.

Some things to consider:

- Are you using extensions to the Python DB API that might not be implemented in both?
- Are the two libraries translating MySQL datatypes to Python datatypes the same way?
- Is there example code you could post?

Comment: I'm afraid there's too little to go on in the code you posted without the stored procedure definition.  Best of luck, good night.